# Can't change style to jQuery:s autocomplete element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've been trying to change the background color of the focused item in jQuerys autocomplete box, but is was harder than I thought.
My mission is to change the blue color to something else. Is that possible?

[image]

It's **not** the hover color. That one I already manage to change. No it's the color that displays when you use the keyboard to change focused item.

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/18b15bw1

I've used the exact code from the example that jQuery provides: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

I just added this to make the hover red:

```
 .ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover {
     background: red;
 }
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `.ui-state-active` class as well:

```
.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover, .ui-menu-item .ui-state-active {
  background: red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bs42k52w/)**

Actually, you don't even need your hover rule, this handles both mouse and keyboard:

```
.ui-menu-item .ui-state-active {
  background: red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/b9xmbbbd/)**

Comment: I was searching for hours to find the right combo so I did not change the other active jquery elements on the page, thanks for this answer!